# Not able to POST form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap form which contains Various fields which need to be entered by User.On Submission of this form I want it to send data to WebService.

But it is not sending user input data of the form.Here is the HTML Markup.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="~/RegisterUser" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> First Name </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and When I am seeing in chrome I am getting `Request URL:http://localhost:54990/RegisterUser` as Request URL.
Is there anything I am missing on the `form` or `input field` creation.

My Service is correct and I am able to get the debugger breakpoint over there with no data that was posted from User.

Comment: What is the WebService? What is ~/User?

Comment: Try placing the full URL in the `action`

Comment: @Chris Sorry it was typo,i updated to `URL:http://localhost:54990/RegisterUser`

Comment: @WesFoster `URL:http://localhost:54990/RegisterUser` This is the full URL

Comment: RegisterUser is some function than I assume? You may need the name="firstName" attribute in your input tag. Assuming the register users has a property of the same name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your input doesn't have a `name`. Only named inputs can be successful.

Comment: Okay.So, it should be like ` <div class="col-sm-9"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required> </div>`.Is it correct Now ?

Comment: @Lara: I think what he means is that `<input name="SomeName" type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required />
`

Comment: @FahadUddin — Isn't that the same except you've reordered the attributes and added a superfluous `/`?

Comment: @Quentin: It is. My bad. I did not read his comment properly.

Answer (score 4):

You always give all fields that should be accessed after posting a form a `name`-attribute. So do something like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName" required />`
```

then you can access it by using

`$_POST['FirstName']` or however you want to access the values posted.

Comment: They haven't mentioned PHP, so that may not be relevant to the question.